# Select Max then Increment & THEN Update another ROW Oracle - concurrent issue

Tags: oracle, select, concurrency, sequence

We have a requirement where we need to select the MAX value then increment and then update another row based on Date, I have given below the example

| Date | Name | GENERATED _Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 July | John | **CD001** |
| 30 July | Rocky | **CD002** |
| 30 July | Tina | **CD003** |
| 31 July | John | **CD001** |
| 31 July | Rocky | **CD002** |
| 30 July | Vicky | **CD004** |
| 30 July | John | **CD001** |

We have the blow logic implemented in a package

**Step 1**: Select NVL (MAX (Generated_Code), CD000) from table BASED on Date

**Step 2**: Increment it by 1

**Step 3**: Update Generated code for the newly inserted row

**Special Scenario** - If a same Name comes again for the same date then we have use the same GENERATED_Code, please see last row above, we have some check inbetween the steps and implemented it.

*Example of how code works* - if a new record with Date: **31 July** ad Name **Arron** is inserted then, 1 - get CD002, increatement - CD003, then update the newly inserted recode like below

| Date | Name | GENERATED _Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 July | John | **CD001** |
| 30 July | Rocky | **CD002** |
| 30 July | Tina | **CD003** |
| 31 July | John | **CD001** |
| 31 July | Rocky | **CD002** |
| 30 July | Vicky | **CD004** |
| 30 July | John | **CD001** |
| **31 July** | **Arron** | **CD003** |

**PROBLEM**: Concurrency, When this package is called from a JAVA code concurrently, the same GENERTED_code is applied twice for different Name, the problem lies with the select MAX() value. How to implement this, is sequence the only way, we do not want to create multiple sequence for each date, how to handle this?

Comment: Do all these operations in one [Transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/transact.htm#CNCPT016).

Comment: Yes these are in one Transaction

Comment: Sequence is a "no go" if you don't want holes (they are not rollbacked), and anyway this will not allow to have numbering starting at 1 each day. You can do it in a PL/SQL procedure looping on a "SELECT with a row_number() over(partition by trunc(date)" and catching the dup key exception (-1), retrying until OK. This doesn't guarantee that the order by generated_code will be strictly equals to the order by date if you keep hour/min/second in your date, and the procedure should be ready to handle several rows (unless you pass the PK of your table as argument)

Comment: Don't do this. It violates normalization rules for data consistency. A value stored in a row should never depend on other rows. If you want to number the rows within dates, do so at query time, not at insert time.